# How do I import excel file to python and check column for duplicates?

Tags: python, excel

I have collected some data from a system that includes just over 7000 different selections and I am hoping to import this data into python and treat column A (all of the data) as a list and then check for duplicates.

The desired outcome would to be writing all selections that are duplicates to a txt file.

I have stumbled across separate pieces of code that may do the trick but don't know how I'd compile them to create a solution to my problem.

Code for finding duplicates below - I would of course change the print results to write to file...

```
def FindDuplicates(in_list):  
    unique = set(in_list)  
    for each in unique:  
        count = in_list.count(each)  
        if count > 1:  
            print 'There are duplicates in this list'  
            return True  
    print 'There are no duplicates in this list'  
    return False
```

My struggle now is essentially replacing 'in_list' with column A of the imported excel file.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Jack

Comment: Is your question about importing or about removing duplicates?

Comment: Are you trying to analyse an `.xlsx` an `.xls` or a `.csv` file?

Comment: @GalAbra I am trying to find duplicates in a list that is currently in excel. So both I suppose.

Comment: @MartinEvans Hi, it is an xls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's `Counter` to help determine if there are duplicates:

```
import xlrd
from collections import Counter

def FindDuplicates(in_list):
    counts = Counter(in_list)
    two_or_more = [item for item, count in counts.items() if count >= 2]
    print two_or_more
    return len(two_or_more) > 0

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"input.xls")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
col_a = [sheet.row(row)[0].value for row in range(sheet.nrows)] # Read in all rows

print FindDuplicates(col_a)
```

Python by default cannot read in an `.xls` file so you will need to install a package to help. I have used `xlrd` to read in the older format `.xls` file. This could be installed by using:

```
pip install xlrd
```

---

If you are able to save your Excel file in `.csv` format, then the following code could be used:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

def FindDuplicates(in_list):
    counts = Counter(in_list)
    two_or_more = [item for item, count in counts.items() if count >= 2]
    print two_or_more
    return len(two_or_more) > 0

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    col_a = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f_input)]

print FindDuplicates(col_a)
```

Comment: How do I point the script to look at the right part of the excel doc? I'm unsure of how to get the list from the excel file into the python script.

Comment: Hi Martin, if I were to save the excel file as a .csv would I still need to install a package for python to read it? As I'm trying to avoid installing further packages if possible. Or is there any other potential solutions without requiring further installations? Cheers

Comment: If you can save as a `.csv` file then you can use the build in Python `csv` library to read it very easily. I have added a possible solution for you in the answer.