# Achieved finding quadruplicate in single column but how to write into a new csv file?

Tags: python

I followed the python script by Martin Evans in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135870/how-do-i-import-excel-file-to-python-and-check-column-for-duplicates), and unsure how to write into a new excel spreadsheet.

Here's the modified script to search for quadruplicate in :

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

def FindQuad(in_list):
    counts = Counter(in_list)
    four_or_more = [item for item, count in counts.items() if count >= 4]
    print(four_or_more)
    return len(four_or_more) > 0

with open('Finding quadruplicates.csv', 'rt') as f_input:
    col_a = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f_input)]

print(FindQuad(col_a))

with open('newfile.csv','w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames=['IDs']
    write=csv.writer(f_input)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for key, value in FindQuad.items():
        writer.writerow(list(key) + [value])
```

My VSC terminal shows this error:

NameError: name 'writer' is not defined. Did you mean: 'write'?

Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Script edited after @PCM comments and modified for possible indentation error:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

def FindQuad(in_list):
    counts = Counter(in_list)
    four_or_more = [item for item, count in counts.items() if count >= 4]
    print(four_or_more)
    return len(four_or_more) > 0

with open('Finding quadruplicates.csv', 'rt') as f_input:
    col_a = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f_input)]

# print(FindQuad(col_a))

    with open('newfile.csv','w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames=['IDs']
        write=csv.writer(csvfile)
        write.writerow(fieldnames)
        for key, value in FindQuad.items():
            write.writerow(list(key) + [value])
```

Now I get this error:

line 19, in 
for key, value in FindQuad.items():
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'items'

Can someone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the variable as `write`, so use that word only -

```
write=csv.writer(f_input)
write.writerow(fieldnames) # You didn't declare writer, so it is write
for key, value in FindQuad.items():
    write.writerow(list(key) + [value])
```

Or, you could declare it as `writer=csv.writer(f_input)`, and then use `writer` for the code.

Comment: Thanks @PCM. I made the correction as you suggested and now this error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. So how do I fix this?